# Javascript's equivalent to PHP's $$varName

Tags: php, javascript, variable-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access javascript variable value by creating another variable via concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993013/how-to-access-javascript-variable-value-by-creating-another-variable-via-concaten)

In PHP I can have:

```
$theVariable = "bigToe";
$bigToe = "is broken";
```

such that:

```
echo "my ".$theVariable." ".$$theVariable;
```

would display

```
my bigToe is broken
```

How would I go about doing something similar to that in JavaScript?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993013/how-to-access-javascript-variable-value-by-creating-another-variable-via-concaten

Comment: You'd be better off using an associative array for that in PHP, or an object in JavaScript.

Comment: @Code Duck: There are cases where it's useful.

Comment: Don't try and implement other programming languages mistakes

Comment: @Jed Smith - there's not anything you can do with a dynamic variable you can't do with an associative array or an object, and this method is much less maintainable.

Answer (score 5):

**There is a pretty good write-up on Dynamic Variables in JavaScript here:**

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/dynamic-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `window` array instead of `eval`:

```
var bigToe = "big toe";
window[bigToe] = ' is broken';
alert("my " + bigToe + window[bigToe]);
```

Comment: Why would you prefer the window[] over eval()?

Comment: @baiano: Removes any security worries that are introduced with `eval`'s usage, plus referencing a dictionary is *always* faster then evaluating Javascript just to produce a solution.

Comment: @baiano - simply because I always tend to avoid using `eval` if I can possibly help it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @Jed Smith: referencing a dynamic property of window is not always safe, particularly if it is a dynamic function call, but it is of course safer than `eval`. E.g., if "bigToe" were created by shared user data, it could be used to overwrite some important global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
eval("variableName")
```

Although you have to be sure you know the exact value your evaling as it can be used for script injection if you're passing it untrusted content

Comment: You definitely should't use eval

Comment: @Fabien: I know that eval has a huge number of security risks, i even commented explicitly to that effect.  That said the only way to achieve what was requested is eval, saying "you definitely shouldn't use eval" implies that my answer should have been "it's impossible" which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `eval` function

```
var theVariable = "bigToe";
var bigToe = "is broken";
console.log('my '+theVariable+' '+eval(theVariable));
```

Another way is to use the `window` object, which holds the key-value pair for each global variable.  It can accessed as an array:

```
var theVariable = "bigToe";
var bigToe = "is broken";
console.log('my '+theVariable+' '+window[theVariable]);
```

Both methods print the answer to the Firebug console.

Comment: the "window" option is the best. If your var is not in the global scope (for example declared in a function), you should replace "window" by "this", or the containing object name

Comment: @Fabien: if the var is not in the global scope, then using 'this' as a prefix will not help you -- the only reason that 'this' and 'window' are often interchangable is because 'this' is always the global object when a function is called without a base and window is merely an alias to that global object.